# What is the best charset encoding for sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I tried with `mysqli_set_charset("cp1251")` and with `utf8`, not working.

I've tryed to insert string in sql like this `htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");`
and for accent letters working perfectly but for russian characters the result is like this **Øóôóòèíñêèé Ìèõàèë**.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Try also setting the connection encoding. `$c=new mysqli($a,$ab,$ac,$d); $c->set_charset("utf8");`

Comment: @Michel, thanks but I tried a lot of methods including and this, and not working.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to use the same character set in the complete data chain. Mixed encodings will always cause problems.

- Set the table or column encoding to charset x
- Set the database connection encoding to charset x
- Set the internal encoding of PHP to charset x or convert the string
- Set the input and output client (mysql console, browser or cli) encoding to charset x
- When you are using a browser check the encoding which is set in the http header, too. Depending on the browser this value might overwrite an exisiting meta tag in the html header!